# Obj-C, function to return index of nsstring found in nsarray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

I've been looking to see if I can find a function like indexOf.

I have an array.

```
self.data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple", @"lemon", @"pear", nil];
```

Looking for a function to return which would look for lemon and return 1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about [`indexOfObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:)?

```
NSUInteger index = [self.data indexOfObject:@"lemon"];
```

Comment: This will not work. Since strings are pointers to objects you cannot compare them for equality.

Comment: `indexOfObject:` uses `isEqual:` to check for equality. And this works perfectly fine for NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
-(int)indexOfString:(NSString *)string inArray:(NSArray *)array {
    for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] class] == [NSString class]) {
            if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:string]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The other answer using `-indexOfObject:` is better.